# How to avoid calling 'startx' upon ssh login

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, startx

my current situation is that in my .zprofile file I have the following line I found somewhere on the internet

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

I think it's supposed to see if there is a display and if so it starts and x server which allow i3 window manager to run later on. This works great except for when I try to SSH in, as soon as I type in my password it errors out and closes the connection with the following message :

"Error Opening Display!"

I'm assuming this is because it's trying to start an x server upon login, how do I fix this? I'm assuming I need to change some things around so that startx isn't called if I'm ssh'ing in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if `$SSH_CLIENT` is empty as well as `$DISPLAY`.  For example:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && -z $SSH_CLIENT && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

Alternatively, use `$SSH_CONNECTION` or `$SSH_TTY`